# android google map set country attributes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i am using this xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraBearing="112.5"
    map:cameraTargetLat="34.8545"
    map:cameraTargetLng="37.0261"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="false"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="false"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="false"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
```

to make google map zoom to a country but all i get is a screen with line blue in the middle, what am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `map:cameraTilt="30"` and `map:cameraBearing="112.5"` and see what happens.

Comment: now i got screen with two spaces, one all blue, one all white

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your xml code in my xml file and successfully run on my device,but with different coordinates...

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
map:cameraBearing="112.5"
map:cameraTargetLat="18.5182355"
map:cameraTargetLng="73.8792761"
map:cameraTilt="30"
map:cameraZoom="13"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiCompass="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="false"
map:uiTiltGestures="true"
map:uiZoomControls="false"
map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
```

the blue line you are seeing is may be due to wrong lat-lon coordinates..